# Large 12 kWh 18650 Lithium-ion power pack - best nSmP configuration

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, protection, cell-balancing

I need to build a 12 kWh lithium-ion power pack for an e-drive system.  The cells will be Panasonic NCR 'B' at 3.4 Ah 18650, which have been sourced at about $3.75 a cell.  Approximately 1,000 cells are needed.  Power is 15 kW.  I am well aware of safety matters and issues with charging strings of li-ion.  I would like to break this pack down into units of 1 to 2 kWh each, to be charged independently.  A 20S balance-protection board can manage a 20S5P = 1,250 Wh configuration.  A smart BMS will be investigated for the 2nd phase of this project.  At C/2, the unit would require a 650 W 84 V 8 A CCCV charger.

Is there a standard for HV e-drive power packs?  The Leaf and Tesla are at about 400 V.  A 5S2Px[20S5P] will provide approximately 400 V at 12.5 kWh.  Is there a recommended, preferred, or popular configuration?  Where can I find such a charger?

Sorry but @DaveTweed is wrong and this question is substantially different from the previous question.  And there is no answer to the previous question anyways.  Has he read the previous answer?  The previous question was formulated in the form of "how is it done" before it was edited and then it went on hold - so no answer is forthcoming.  The new question is very specific and asks if there is a recommended configuration, after explaining all the parameters.

Can @DaveTweed explain how the answer to the previous question is in any way a meaningful answer to this very important question?  The previous answer is "this is too expensive - don't do it".  Is this the intellectual level of Stack Exchange that DaveTweed prefers?  Can DaveTweed read the silly comments to this question and tell me if they are justified?

(question is continuation of [Large 10 kWh 18650 Lithium-ion power pack - What configuration? [on hold]](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/317678/11683))

Comment: I don't think you'll find a standard. So tailor it to your needs, about which you have told us nothing.

Comment: "I am well aware of safety matters and issues with charging strings of li-ion." But you're just going to ignore them? Electric vehicles use much larger cells so there aren't as many to manage, and they manage them all.

Comment: @Finbarr -- Did I say I will "ignore" safety issues?  What makes you think so that you are saying this?  Please read again.  And you are wrong.  Tesla uses 18650s.  There really aren't "larger" cylindrical than 18650s.  26650s are not very common, and are expensive.  And I do not want to use LiPo.

Comment: @BrianDrummond "of which you have told us nothing" -- I have said that this is for an e-drive.  Please read again.

Comment: @Finbar "EVs use larger cells aren't many to manage".  Wrong.  Tesla Model S power pack is made of 7,000 to 9,000 18650 cells.

Comment: The Tesla Model 3 is using 2170 cells which are about 50% larger than a 18650.  But these cells are not available on the market.

Comment: Asking essentially the same question after having the first one closed is not going to win you any friends here. Please edit your original question if you have improvements to make to it.

Comment: @DaveTweed -- The questions are different. I have consulted with a lot of people here on how to reformulate the question.  The first one was too general and did not get any proper answer.  So you are wrong.  I was told NOT to edit the original question.  But to put in a new question with link to old.  So many negative people here.  I am leaving this place for good.

Comment: @DaveTweed --  Nobody except for one guy knows anything about what I am talking about, but all wish to criticize my question, tell me how bad it is, and tell me it cannot be done, without having the foggiest idea what I am talking about.  What is the point of being in a forum of nay sayers who have never seen an 18650 before, anyways?  One guy was complaining that I am ignoring safety issues!  Bunch of holier-than-thou losers who have never built much except what the RC kit has taught them.

Comment: @DaveTweed -- you seem to be very quiet.  Please come on chat and explain your action.

Comment: "*I am leaving this place for good.*" but you're still here? "*Bunch of holier-than-thou losers who have never built much except what the RC kit has taught them.*" On the contrary. This site has many very active members with decades of engineering experience and who give freely of their time to answer questions. Calling them "*losers* is childish. If you are not getting the response you expect then take a step back and try to read your questions with the eyes of someone seeing them for the first time.

Comment: The size of the pack that you are proposing is getting you into the area where the car companies are working and using their own propeitary BMS and chargers etc., would you consider the larger pouch cells such as here - http://hybridautocenter.com/HAC4/index.php?option=com_hikashop&ctrl=product&task=show&cid=96&name=7kwh-lithium-battery-pack-chevrolet-volt-155v-45ah-42-cells&Itemid=605.  I build a lot of .5 - 1KWh battery packs with 18650.  If you want to bounce ideas off of me leave a comment here and I will give you my email.